# RSS-Feed and Latex

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, rss

I love using RSS-feed and I wanted to use it for this site too. The problem is that my RSS-Reader does not render Latex so I get the *source code* of Latex and trying to render Latex in my head is not so easy! Wouldn't it be better if the Latex formulas are sent as pictures so that the RSS-Reader can do a better job.

I am also open to suggestions of an RSS-Reader (for linux), which can render Latex or Mathjax or whatever.

Comment: Can RSS handle embedded images? Is it a sign of my age that I'm even asking this?

Comment: [This StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055687/conversion-of-mathjax-in-rss-feed-to-images-also-converts-non-latex-strings) question suggests that MathJax (what we use here) cannot be used in RSS feeds due to lack of JavaScript. The comments suggest a work-around, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what it means.

Comment: Though [this MathOverflow post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132546/is-there-an-rss-reader-for-mathematicians) has a few suggestions.

Comment: I personally would just use the chatjax bookmarklet and click it  to render all dollary formulae on the page.

Comment: @manishearth how would that work?

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html

Comment: @Manishearth: Sadly, that does not work for web browsers with built-in RSS feeders (e.g., [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) 12.16 that I use).

Comment: @ChrisWhite yes, RSS does handle embedded images.

Comment: I'm making a new RSS feed reader optimised for readability. Kindly let me know which features do you want?  One feature I guess is rendering LaTeX equations.  What else?  Also kindly tell me your favorite RSS feed reader.